# Regex, PHP and Wordpress plugins - Can't make my regex work

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm using a regex pattern to locate a string to be deleted, which is delimited by two strings (say, "START" and "FINISH").
So it's STARTsome_string_to_deleteFINISH

Problem is that START and FINISH strings are html tags which have < > characters.

When I use online regex testers, they pattern works fine but when I insert the expression in Wordpress plugins that I use (e.g. WPEMatico that handles RSS to New Posts), I keep getting errors.

I tried escaping special characters with backslash. Doesn't work.

Any advice?

Here's an example of the string I used:

```
==========================================
(\<!-- Facebook Comments Plugin for WordPress).+?(<\/comments>)
==========================================
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide [mcve], so you can get help from the community.

Comment: Please put relevant text / code into the question as text, not as image.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have "single-line mode" turned on. Single-line mode allows the `.` to match newlines.

For example [this regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/3c9zM4/1/) doesn't work because single-line mode isn't turned on. But [this one](https://regex101.com/r/3c9zM4/2/) does work.

If your regular expression engine supports single line mode, you might be able to enable single-line mode by preceding your regex with `(?s)`: `(?s)<!-- Facebook Comments Plugin for WordPress.+?<\/comments>`. If not, then something like this should work: [`<!-- Facebook Comments Plugin for WordPress(?:.|[\r\n])+?<\/comments>`](https://regex101.com/r/3c9zM4/4/)

Note I've removed the `()` because they were superfluous unless you actually want to capture the text.